# How to request fresh data from repository and overcome entity manager persist return of the same entity in doctrine?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have consumer that handle messages. As it is a consumer it handle all messages during the same request.

So, my request like

```
$box = $this->boxRepository->findOneBy['id'= > $message->getId()];
```

will take $box on the first request and then return the same entity with 'fixed' properties during handling another messages with the same Id. So:

```
$box->getName() // 'fooBox'
```

Then from another microservice i changed value in DB:

```
Update BOX b set b.name = 'newValue'
```

But consumer will take box and show me, that $box->getName() is still **'fooBox'**

I can take new value, by refreshing it, like:

```
$box = $this->boxRepository->findOneBy['id'= > $message->getId()];

$this->em->refresh($box);
```

But is this a way, to set some force flag or maybe something else, to take actual value on each request without refreshing?

Comment: that other microservice does not use a Box object but uses DQL/SQL directly? is it done during the same http request or a completely different thread/process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use any standart `\Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository` methods

```php
/**
 * @method Entity|null find($id, $lockMode = null, $lockVersion = null)
 * @method Entity|null findOneBy(array $criteria, array $orderBy = null)
 * @method Entity[]    findAll()
 * @method Entity[]    findBy(array $criteria, array $orderBy = null, $limit = null, $offset = null)
 */
```

you always get cached results at second and later invocation. So `\Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager::refresh` is mandatory for getting last data from DB.

Using DQL or native SQL (maybe at custom repository method) is another approach.